# How can I get the default content of WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way where I can get the default output of the_content in WordPress post? Some of the plugin is using add_filter to the content to add their desired result like related post plugins where they add the result at the end of the content of a post. What I want to happen is to get the default formatting functions of WordPress core without any additional filters from other plugins.

Comment: I think you can get the original content with `$post->post_content`, if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: If I use that I will only get a plain text coming from database. The result most probably will be just a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove filter function.

```
remove_filter( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority );
```

For more please refer below link

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Comment: Yes i could definitely use that, but it will not be dynamic. What I mean by that is every time you install a plugin that has add filter to the content I need to manually use the remove filter. I want to have a dynamic function that will only get the formatting functions from WordPress only.

Comment: @user1645213  You can try it like this
`// when the init hook fires
add_action( 'init', 'sillo_remove_that_filter' );

function sillo_remove_that_filter() {
    // remove the filter
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'first_paragraph' );
}`

Put remove_filter function in function.php file that remove from hole site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the_content` filter itself to get the post object or the content , you can modify it or you can unhook it and again hook it as per your requirement .

If I have understood your requirement this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) will help you, if you need something different please ask me.

Comment: are you referring to inserting additional content in the_content? I want to have a dynamic function that will only get the default formatting functions from WordPress only

Comment: oh ! sorry , please let me know are you trying to refer to any specific function ,or the main query in your function .

Comment: as there is upvote on an answer referring remove_filter, have you tried to achieve what you want to achieve  by adding the same filter on a later priority .

Comment: Yes that could definitely work but you will always need to manually create a remove filter every time a plugin is added that has function that will add filter to the_content. What I really want to achieve is to have the_content without any of the add_filters coming from other plugins or custom code, just the default result coming from WordPress

Comment: Have you tried to use `pre_get_posts` ? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for responding to my question I think I got it somehow but need to run more test. What I did was I replicate the process on how `the_content()` function of WordPress work. Base from my research there are 10 default filters coming from WordPress core you can see on this link: [read here](https://codeseekah.com/2012/02/26/what-the_content-goes-through/#comment-990628)

I just created my own function like `the_content()` from WordPress and apply the default filters to my own function. Put this code in your functions.php

```
if(!function_exists(default_post_content)){
    function default_post_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
        $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
        $content = apply_filters( 'default_post_content', $content );
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );

        echo do_shortcode($content);
    }

    add_filter( 'default_post_content', array( $wp_embed, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );
    add_filter( 'default_post_content', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed'), 8 );
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'wptexturize');
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'convert_smilies');
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'convert_chars');
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'wpautop');
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'shortcode_unautop');
    add_filter ( 'default_post_content', 'prepend_attachment'); 
}
```

Then for example in your single page template(single.php) instead of using the usual the_content I can use my function `default_post_content();`. Now I don't need to worry about any of the plugins that create additional data to `the_content()` function.